# When injected into a program's memory space, how do you read each byte from 0 to 0xFFFFFFFFF? I am creating a pattern scanner

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to create a pattern scanner, to find every byte sequence starting with "MZ" (4d5a) inside a programs memory. For that I'm injecting a DLL into the target program.

I try to look for the "MZ" pattern as I see some sneaky modules that are unlinking themselves from the modulelist.

From within the program's memory space I was hoping to iterate from 0 to 0xFFFFFFFFF and check for byte patterns. By simply doing something like this:

```
unsigned i = 0;
while (i < 0xFFFFFFFFF) {
    if ((BYTE*) i != NULL) {
        std::cout << "Print byte: " << ConvertToHexString( (BYTE*) i) << std::endl;
    }
    i++;
}
```

`ConvertToHexString` successfully converts `(BYTE*)` to `std::string`.

I thought it was that easy, even if I hit memory I wasn't allowed to read. I thought my `NULL` check was sufficient. Seemed it was not. However, if I start from the modulebase (`uintptr_t pModuleBase = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle(NULL)`), I can actually see the bytes.

Below is my code:

`DllMain`:

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(

        ...snip...
        CloseHandle(CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)SignatureScanner, moduleHandle, 0, 0));
        ...snip...
}
```

`SignatureScanner`:

```
DWORD WINAPI SignatureScanner(HMODULE moduleHandle)
{
    // Create Console
    AllocConsole();
    FILE* f;
    freopen_s(&f, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);

    // Get module base
    uintptr_t pModuleBase = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    while (true)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1) & 1)
        {
             unsigned i = 0;
             while (i < 0xFFFFFFFFF) {
                if ((BYTE*) i != NULL) {
                   std::cout << "Print byte: " << ConvertToHexString( (BYTE*) i) << std::endl;
                }
                i++;
             } 
        }

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD2) & 1)
        {
            break;
        }

        Sleep(100);
    }

    fclose(f);
    FreeConsole();
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(moduleHandle, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why inject? Read it with ReadProcessMemory. Then you'll need to learn how to find out which pages are mapped.

Comment: Reading memory that is not mapped to a process will trigger a page fault. The OS will then see if it can map that thing into the programs address space - if it can (because the thing was just swapped out or similar) your good and continue on your merry way. If it cannot, that's a hard error and your program is terminated. In short; you cannot simply scan from address zero to max memory (unless you are the OS). You can only access addresses that the OS has already assigned to your process. Also remember virtual memory is a thing. Each process has its own virtual memory space != Physical address

Comment: In the days of CP/M or DOS, your approach *might* work. But not these days. Memory management with modern CPUs and Operating Systems is *much* more complicated.

Comment: Iterating 4 billion times is going to be incredibly slow. Instead, find out which memory pages are mapped and iterate those only.

Comment: In order to find out which addresses are mapped, you can use the [`VirtualQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualquery) or [`VirtualQueryEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualqueryex) function. VirtualQueryEx is only required for obtaining information about other processes.

Comment: What's so special about the address 0xFFFFFFFFF? Why do you want to read the entire memory below that address, but nothing above it?

Comment: @IInspectable: I suppose he is using 32-bit applications and wrote one `F` too many.

Comment: @and Maybe, maybe not. The address `0xFFFFFFFFF` appears in the question title, in the question body, and twice in code. That's four times in total. That's way beyond the threshold of subscribing it to a typo for my taste. And makes you wonder why developers don't just use what's there to improve readability. Like `0xF'FFFF'FFFF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Virtual Address Space**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/virtual-address-space)

> The virtual address space for a process is the set of virtual memory
>   addresses that it can use. The address space for each process is
>   private and cannot be accessed by other processes unless it is shared.
>
> **Default Virtual Address Space for 32-bit Windows**:
>
> Low 2GB (**0x00000000** through **0x7FFFFFFF**)    - Used by the process.
>
> High 2GB (**0x80000000** through **0xFFFFFFFF**) - Used by the system.

You are trying to read the address space that does not belong to your process, try to use `VirtualProtectEx` + `ReadProcessMemory`.

In addition, It is not recommended to use `CreateThread` in `DllMain`: [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices#general-best-practices)(You don't need to inject Dll as well)

Then, we don't need to read all the address. A module is an executable file or DLL. Each process consists of one or more modules. The first module is the executable file. It is mapped into the module base address. So you could `ReadProcessMemory` from the module base address(Refer to [PE Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format).)

You could use the `EnumProcessModules` + `GetModuleInformation` to get the base address and the size of the linear space that the module occupies, in bytes.

Or You can just use `EnumProcessModules` + `GetModuleBaseName` to check modules list and confirm which module has unlinked.

Comment: Calling `CreateThread` from `DllMain` is perfectly safe. [Does creating a thread from DllMain deadlock or doesn't it?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070904-00/?p=25283) explains the operations that aren't safe.